# Oracle get last 10 days sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the last 10 days from now on
I currently have following Oracle sql query to get the last 10 dates.

```
WITH DATES AS (
  SELECT sysdate - 10 AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 9  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 8  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 7  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 6  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 5  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 4  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 3  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 2  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate - 1  AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate      AS value_date FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT sysdate + 1  AS value_date FROM dual
```

But I want a more proper and efficient way to get the past 10 dates. An Union query looks pretty dirty.
How do I do this in Oracle SQL?

Comment: You are looking for something like the `VALUES` clause (http://modern-sql.com/feature/values), but Oracle still doesn't support it. You can write a recursive query if you like this.  better than the `UNION` query. It should be `UNION ALL` by the way, as there are no duplicates to remove - don't give the DBMS more work to do than necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a more compact equivalent with CONNECT BY clause:

```
SELECT trunc( sysdate ) - level + 2
FROM dual
CONNECT BY rownum <= 12
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a50e25/5

```
| TRUNC(SYSDATE)-LEVEL+2 |
|------------------------|
|   2017-09-15T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-14T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-13T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-12T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-11T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-10T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-09T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-08T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-07T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-06T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-05T00:00:00Z |
|   2017-09-04T00:00:00Z |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results as your query using a hierarchical query (also using `TRUNC()` to truncate the date to midnight at the start of the day):

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 11 + LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
```

or, use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH days ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + 1 FROM days WHERE dt <= SYSDATE
)
SELECT dt FROM days
```